Is pastors-btw.top a scam?
I just received an invitation to go to bitcoin it directed me to payout section it only asks for email where to send the money. Wants to know account number it telling that I have 106000 the there the submit to manager is this legit also paystore ?

See How to tell if a cryptocurrency exchange or trading platform is trustworthy?

Whenever you're told you supposedly own money that you know nothing about, it's pretty safe to assume it is a scam. At some point they'll likely tell you to send them some bitcoin to "verify" your account or to pay an advance "fee" or "tax". Don't send them anything, you'll never get it back and they'll come up with excuses to make you send them even more.
See: Is it normal to be asked for an advance fee on a withdrawal?
